# Tensorflow: tf.estimator does not work with large CSV training files (~7GB)

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to train a canned estimator `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` for a binary classification problem

```
def input_fn_train(features, labels, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256]     
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
    hidden_units=hidden_units,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
              learning_rate=0.01,
              l1_regularization_strength=0.001))

estimator.train(input_fn=lambda:input_fn_train(train_x, train_y, batch_size), steps=train_steps)
```

But, when I try to run `estimator.train`, I get the following error

`[libprotobuf FATAL T:\src\github\tensorflow\cmake_build\protobuf\src\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\message_lite.cc:68] CHECK failed: (byte_size_before_serialization) == (byte_size_after_serialization): tensorflow.GraphDef was modified concurrently during serialization.`

I am pretty sure it has to do with the size of the CSV training file stored in the variable `train_x` because I tried the same code with smaller training CSV files (~500 MB) and it works perfectly fine.

My CSV training file has 801 columns (including the label 0 or 1 ), the 800 features are numeric values between 0 and 1 (float). The training file has more than 1 million of instances ( 801 x 1172480 ),

Also, it is important to mention that `train_x` , the variable that contain the data from the 7GB CSV, is successfully populated with the 7GB data in memory. Moreover, I don't have any problems with memory overflow ( my computer has 128 GB of memory RAM), so the only thing left is that Tensorflow [unfortunately] can't handle CSV training files of that size.

I am planning to split the training set in different files and use the checkpoint feature to keep training over those files, but I am not sure if that is the optimal solution, any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19657). Says: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x) will embed x as a constant tensor inside the graph. Using an initializable iterator with a placeholder would be more appropriate.

Comment: thanks @swiftg but unfortunately they are not using estimators, how would you introduce a placeholder in the input function?

Comment: [This may be of use](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators).   [And this](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance). Rather than read the entire CSV at once, you may need to create a function to read it in chunks and feed it small batches at a time.